# Filtering when using custom column type in Slick

Tags: scala, slick, slick-2.0

I'm having some difficulties querying/filtering in Slick 2.1.0 when using a custom column type.
A simplified version of my problem:

```
import scala.slick.driver.MySQLDriver.simple._

sealed class Status(val intValue: Int)
case object Active extends Status(1)
case object Disabled extends Status(2)
case object Deleted extends Status(3)

case class TableMapping(id: Long, status: Status)

class MyTableDefinition(tag: Tag) extends Table[TableMapping](tag, "sometable") {
  implicit val statusColumnType = MappedColumnType.base[Status, Int](statusToInt, intToStatus)

  def id = column[Long]("ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def status = column[Status]("STATUS", O.NotNull, O.Default(Active))
  def * = (id, status) <> (TableMapping.tupled, TableMapping.unapply)

  private def statusToInt(s: Status): Int = s.intValue
  private def intToStatus(i: Int): Status = i match {
    case 1 => Active
    case 2 => Disabled
    case _ => Deleted
  }
}

class MyTableDao {
    val Items = TableQuery[MyTableDefinition]
    def byId(id: Long)(implicit session: Session): Option[TableMapping] = {
      Items.filter(_.status =!= Deleted).firstOption
    }
}
```

I get a compile error on this:

```
Items.filter(_.status =!= Deleted).firstOption
```

The error states:

```
value =!= is not a member of scala.slick.lifted.Column[Status]
[error] def byId(id: Long)(implicit session: Session): Option[TableMapping] =
  Items.filter(_.status =!= Deleted).firstOption
```

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong? Maybe there is a much better way of doing this that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 9):

The thing is that the Scala compiler will look for an implicit convertion for `Deleted.type` instead of `Status`.

As `Deleted` is declared as an `object` it is not a class, its actual class is `Deleted.type`, so you just have to help the compiler to understand that is actually a `Status`. How? You can try

```
class MyTableDao {
val Items = TableQuery[MyTableDefinition]

def byId(id: Long)(implicit session: Session): Option[TableMapping] =
    Items.filter(_.status =!= Deleted.asInstanceOf[Status]).firstOption
}
```

That'll do it.

Let me know if it did work, I'm facing a similar problem and I was able to get rid of it doing that.

Comment: Still relevant in Slick 3. Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't do this on a DAO. This is expensive. Use a type annotation
Ref: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scalaquery/prrMbK0jcR8/GjZ9i3aKEgAJ

Comment: Thank you, Mesi and Rhys! Both tricks worked but went with Rhys's one.

Comment: Is the only way to make this work is to create repository methods that contain the filtering logic in the same class as the table? I'd prefer to not do this, but I haven't figured out how to get the implicit sealed trait column mapper up out of the table class and back down to the business logic that wants to do the filtering.

Answer (score 0):

Your custom type mapper needs to be in scope for the DAO; I'd do something like:

```
trait MyTypeMapper {
  protected implicit val statusColumnType = 
    MappedColumnType.base[Status, Int](_.intValue, intToStatus)

  private def intToStatus(i: Int): Status = i match {
    case 1 => Active
    case 2 => Disabled
    case _ => Deleted
  }
}
```

and then mix the trait into your table mapper and dao:

```
class MyTableDefinition(tag: Tag) 
  extends Table[TableMapping](tag, "sometable")
  with MyTypeMapper {...}

class MyTableDao extends MyTypeMapper{...}
```

Comment: I just tried this approach. It solved my initial compile error. However, I got the following error now:

[error]  found   : Deleted.type
[error]  required: scala.slick.lifted.Column[?]
[error]         Items.filter(_.status =!= Deleted).firstOption

Any ideas?

Comment: I created a small test application for this: [link](https://github.com/ulejon/slickcustomcolumn). If you compile that you'll see two errors when using this approach.

Comment: do `.filter(_.status =!= Deleted.bind)`

Comment: Hm, no dice: value bind is not a member of object se.lejon.customcolumn.Deleted

Comment: then try going direct to primitive type: `.filter(_.status =!= Deleted.intValue.bind)`

Comment: not sure, maybe the MySQL import; in order to run queries normally you'd import from a driver profile (i.e. database connection). Can you run any queries at all?

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @ulejon your git repo doesnt compile

Comment: @RhysBradbury I know, that was the whole point of that repo; to show the compile errors. My comment was: "If you compile that you'll see two errors when using this approach."

Comment: fyi you can fix this with a type signature

Comment: `.filter(_.status =!= (Deleted: Status)`